# Multi-colored lists

Tags: java, swing, layout, colors, jlist

[image]

I have to create 5 Jlists in succession to make their backgrounds look in different colors. My existing code creates these 5 lists without the colors (the default JList). I understand that I can only customize the inside/border of a jlist and not the margin/padding around it? Or Am I wrong and is there a way to it?

Btw, The space above the list is a Jlabel (not shown in the pic above) and the layout managers in use are GroupLayout and GridBagLayout.

**UPDATE**

AT, as per your suggestion, here is a comparison to how the lists look like when surrounded by a jpanel. The lists in the back are the ones with the Jpanel surrounded with a minimal empty border of size 1.

The issue with creating a JPanel with preferredsize overridden is that the jlists are in horizontal jpanel and above them is another jpanel with labels. So, wrapping jlist in a jpanel is not going to do it.

[image]

Comment: *"the margin/padding around it?"*  It seems you mean the panel that *contains the list* should change color?

Comment: Yes. I guess. But, the problem is that each is not contained in a jpanel. All those 5lists are in a single jpanel.

Comment: Put each list in a panel that is added to the 'one panel'.  "5 panels to color them.  One panel to contain them all."

Comment: any other alternatives to it, other than containing each list in a jpanel?

Comment: Probably.  Why the need for alternatives?

Comment: coz, putting it in a panel might just change current dimensions and that would mean that I would have to do a lot of alignment adjustments.

Comment: @Jay : To simplify things, why not make a class like `CustomPanel`, which will extend `JPanel` make it override `getPreferredSize()`, so that they all are of same size, if you are really horrified with alignment adjustments.

Comment: @Gagandeep added an update, explaining why preferredsize wont do it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: prefXXSize combined with an appropriate LayoutManager will solve _all_ layout problems :-)  Still unclear what is wrong with the first screenshot? If that's basically what you want, make the label opaque, set its background to the border color, let the layoutManager center and fill it above the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do have a look at this code example. Is it closer to what you wanted, else you define the changes that needs to be done. I be on them as soon as I get the reply from your side :-)

Here is the outcome :

[image: JLIST]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JListExample
{
    private JList<String> list1;
    private JList<String> list2;
    private JList<String> list3;
    private JList<String> list4;
    private JList<String> list5;
    private CustomPanel panel1;
    private CustomPanel panel2;
    private CustomPanel panel3;
    private CustomPanel panel4;
    private CustomPanel panel5;
    private String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    private int width = 110;
    private int height = 300;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5, 2, 2));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.9;

        panel1 = new CustomPanel(width, height, Color.GRAY, "List 1");
        list1 = new JList<String>(data);
        panel1.add(list1, gbc);
        panel2 = new CustomPanel(width, height, 
                 Color.GREEN.brighter().brighter(), "List 2");
        list2 = new JList<String>(data);         
        panel2.add(list2, gbc);
        panel3 = new CustomPanel(width, height, 
                          Color.ORANGE.brighter(), "List 3");
        list3 = new JList<String>(data);                  
        panel3.add(list3, gbc);
        panel4 = new CustomPanel(width, height, 
                            Color.BLUE.brighter(), "List 4");
        list4 = new JList<String>(data);                    
        panel4.add(list4, gbc);
        panel5 = new CustomPanel(width, height, Color.RED, "List 5");
        list5 = new JList<String>(data);
        panel5.add(list5, gbc);

        contentPane.add(panel1);
        contentPane.add(panel2);
        contentPane.add(panel3);
        contentPane.add(panel4);
        contentPane.add(panel5);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JListExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final int GAP = 5;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color backgroundColour;
    private JLabel titleLabel;

    public CustomPanel(int w, int h, Color c, String title)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        backgroundColour = c;
        titleLabel = new JLabel(title, JLabel.CENTER);
        setBackground(backgroundColour);
        setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));                   
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
        titleLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(titleLabel, gbc);
    }   

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(width, height));
    }
}
```

**LATEST EDIT : **

As rightly pointed by @kleopatra (not something that is new for me :-)), too good judgement call. Done the edit related to that below :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JListExample
{
    private final int GAP = 5;
    private JList<String> list1;
    private JList<String> list2;
    private JList<String> list3;
    private JList<String> list4;
    private JList<String> list5;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;
    private JPanel panel4;
    private JPanel panel5;
    private String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    private int width = 110;
    private int height = 300;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5, 2, 2));      

        panel1 = getPanel(Color.GRAY, "List 1");
        list1 = new JList<String>(data);

        panel2 = getPanel(Color.GREEN.brighter().brighter(), "List 2");
        list2 = new JList<String>(data);         

        panel3 = getPanel(Color.ORANGE.brighter(), "List 3");
        list3 = new JList<String>(data);                  

        panel4 = getPanel(Color.BLUE.brighter(), "List 4");
        list4 = new JList<String>(data);                    

        panel5 = getPanel(Color.RED, "List 5");
        list5 = new JList<String>(data);        

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.9;

        panel1.add(list1, gbc);
        panel2.add(list2, gbc);
        panel3.add(list3, gbc);
        panel4.add(list4, gbc);
        panel5.add(list5, gbc);

        contentPane.add(panel1);
        contentPane.add(panel2);
        contentPane.add(panel3);
        contentPane.add(panel4);
        contentPane.add(panel5);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(610, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel(Color c, String title)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));       
        panel.setBackground(c);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());   
        JLabel label = new JLabel(title, JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;

        panel.add(label, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JListExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. this is what I need. But, its a lot of change to my existing app, layout and adjustments wise. Anyway, I am going to accept this as the answer to this question. I might not use this approach, I am gonna try convince the client to not do this at all :-)

Comment: cough .. here we go again: a) no need to subclass, a JPanel is-a general purpose container that can be configured as needed b) overriding getXXSize to return a fixed size is only marginally better than setting a fixed size

Comment: @kleopatra : THankx for the insight again, added the answer in a hurry, now I realized, exactly what you said, and what BLUNDER I am doing in this POST :-)